# How do I change the account my Google Voice number is associated with?

Tags: google-voice, account-management

When signing up for Google Voice, I accidentally logged in with the wrong Google Account. How can I transfer this number to a different account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to fill out the  [Troubleshooter for Account Transfer](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/static.py?page=ts.cs&ts=1378061).

> Once this transfer is initiated, it may DELETE ALL OF YOUR SUBSCRIBER INFORMATION, on your destination Google Voice account, like your call history, text messages, and voicemails. Your contacts will NOT be migrated however, they will be preserved for both accounts.

The process may take up to five (5) business days after which they will email you the outcome.

It will be easier if the new Google Account does not have a Google Voice number.

Comment: your link is still valid, but update it to point directly to the new form.  See http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=5b958391b871c0e7&hl=en.

Answer (score 1):

I logged into my other Google account then into Google Voice and claimed the same phone number.

The destination account that I wanted my cell phone number associated with did not have a number already attached to it. When I associated the destination account with my cell phone number it came back saying that it was already associated with a different account and would call to confirm that I had put in the correct information.

Google then called me to confirm that the number was correct and then automatically just transferred it.

After the confirmation it sent an e-mail to the incorrect account saying that my cell number was no longer associated with it and that was it.

No wait at all.